# trigger javascript and sql query at same time

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a javascript that plays an audiofile from a list of files when a link is clicked. Page is not reloaded and it works fine.. so far.
Now i'd like to trigger a sql insert query that will update my database with info on what audiofile was played. Since i use e.preventDefault im not loading any new page hence i cannot trigger a sql run that way.
How do i go about this? 
My page is a mix of php and javascript. Below is the javascript part.
Please give me some advice or direction cause i dont know where to start.

```
function audioPlayer(){
            $(document).on("click", "#playlist a", function(e) { 
               e.preventDefault(); 
               $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
               $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making an ajax request to your server? It doesn't require a page refresh and it can be triggered by the click event.

Comment: Mary Jane's recommendation is my answer below

Comment: You want AJAX with JQuery... You can post to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("savetodb.php", {key:value, key2:value2, etc:stuff},       
function (status, data){
if(status == "success"){
console.log(data);
}
});
```

Data is whatever you echo out on your php file that save to DB. Key is the $_POST['key'] like a form is... Just like key2 and etc are keys. So you pass it just like form data.

Or you can use $.get() instead or $.ajax() method too

Hope this helps :)

The console log of data can be where you do whatever u wanna do after it's saved to DB.

In savetodb.php you would just have:

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])){ 
// save value of post to DB 
// if save is successful:
echo "I did something good."; 
}
```

Your console log of data would say "I did something good."

Comment: thanks :) but all of this goes inside the audioPlayer() function?

Comment: The $.post does yes, but the PHP file is separate